# Limit value insertion in SQL

Tags: sql, constraints

I want to insert values between (1 to 12)
Like we have in " varchar(2) " it limits the number of characters we insert
but I want to limit the value we can insert in a field.
How can I do that?

Comment: Which version of SQL are you using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, etc.) ?  The answer to your question is probably vendor specific.

Comment: Microsoft SQL server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your DBMS supports check constraints, you can use one like:

```
CREATE TABLE elbat
             (...
              nmuloc integer,
              ...
              CHECK (nmuloc >= 1 AND nmuloc <= 12),
              ...);
```